# How to display a sprite on the screen in relation to the azimuth

Tags: android, kotlin, game-development, azimuth

I'm making a game on Android using SurfaceView.

I'm currently receiving the azimuth of the device in degrees (from -180 to 180), which is working correctly. I want to be able to show a sprite on the screen when you turn around to it's location, which right now I'm setting randomly between -180 and 180.

Using this code, it works, but it jumps off the screen when the location is not 0 and you have rotated over 180 or under -180. Is there a way to get around this?

```
   private fun setPositionOnScreen(azimuth: Double) {
        val distanceToLocation = azimuth - location
        x = (distanceToLocation * (screenWidth / 180)).toInt()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun setPositionOnScreen(azimuth: Double) {
    var distanceToZombie = azimuth - location
    if(distanceToZombie < -180) distanceToZombie += 360
    else if(distanceToZombie > 180) distanceToZombie -= 360
    x = (distanceToZombie * (screenWidth / 180)).toInt()
}
```